# Is there a way to distinguish between two classes with same properties and methods?

Tags: typescript

I have code that looks similar to following:

```
module A {
    export class Test1 { }
    export class Test2 { }
}

module B {
    export class Test3 { }
    export class Test4 { }
}

function runOnlyInstaceFromA(instance: InstanceType<typeof A[keyof typeof A]>) {

}

runOnlyInstaceFromA(new A.Test1()); // should be allowed
runOnlyInstaceFromA(new B.Test3()); // should not be allowed
```

Unfortunately it doesn't do what I expect because all the classes share same set of properties and methods and typescript cannot tell any difference. Is there any way to handle this other than adding unique property to each class?

Comment: I don't think so. Typescript uses structural typing. That means that if types have the same structure, they are considered to be the same type. But if they really do have the same structure, why does it matter if you pass in one or the other?

Comment: Just to keep usage context clean - "use this function only with stuff from module A". I have one ugly workaround - placing unused private property in classes makes no runtime payload (ts will optimize them out) but makes difference in types.

Comment: Adding a unique (private) field is the accepted solution to this. Classes with private fields, even if they share structure, will be nominally typed